# A tag for Google Domains

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There are several questions concerning [Google Domains](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22google+domains%22) product but no [google-domains](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-domains) tag. [One of them](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/85519) even contains a remark

> FWIW I'd like to tag this "google-domains" and/or similar but I don't have enough rep on webmasters yet.)

Tagging these with [google] and [domains] doesn't seem advisable because most questions with this tag combination are about the effects of domain choice on Google rank.  So I propose that [google-domains](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-domains) tag be created.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've created the [google-domains](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-domains) tag and updated the question you specifically linked to. If you know of others feel free to edit them accordingly.