# Is there an on going tag clean-up / retagging effort?

Tags: support, tags, retagging

I answered a question today slightly related to [google-workspace](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-workspace). The question's core is "domains literacy" (domain registrar, domain hosting, alternatives to handle domain email forwarding ). Looking to refresh what I know about Webmasters SE I found a recent question about Google Domains that looks to me like it requires to be retagged. I suggested an edit.

Doing a quick scan, I found more questions might require to be retagged. Is there an ongoing retag effort or site-specific guidelines for tag clean-up / retagging?

I'm asking because maybe something is handled through a chatroom or another channel.

Related

- [A tag for Google Domains](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1439/52555)
- [Rename tag [google-apps] to [google-workspace] and synonymize [gsuite]?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1804/52555)

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no coordinated retagging effort going on right now. I'm also not aware of any site-specific guidelines that we have for retagging. My initial thoughts are that if there are some questions that need to be retagged go for it, but if there's a ton (dozens+), then that's something that could be helpful to coordinate here on Meta.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Thanks for your quick reply. I might be visiting Webmasters more frequently in the following weeks, as I mentioned, I'm looking to refresh what I know about Webmasters SE and about the related skills as I might have to review / update my domains and related stuff. I will keep your advice in mind.